# How to do automated data sharing between apps on same device on iOS

Tags: ios

I wish to write an iOS app that will act as a database service for other apps on the same device. The other apps would be independent apps that I don't control, so not the same developer group. I want the data exchange to happen all in the background, and it could happen at any times, even when my app is not open. I don't wish that the users sees my app popping up whenever there is a data exchange. There's no limit to the amount of data exchanged.

Is it doable ? If yes, how ?

Options I've explored :

- Url schemas : Small amount of data, and forces the opening of my app.
- UIDocumentInteractionController : opens my app
- Same developer group : not possible.
- Pasteboards : doesn't seem secure, as all apps could intercept it ?
- App extensions: not sure there's one I could use, and I think it requires user triggering.
- Local webserver: works good, but I'm not sure to be able to guarantee that the server stays up at all times.

Did I misunderstood any of the options above ? Did I miss something ? Ideas ?

Comment: Have you looked at the FileProvider extension? I think selecting/saving a file in your app is user triggered, but subsequent changes are notified to you in the background. See `NSFileProviderChangeObserver`